# How to scroll half page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scrollto

Using this native javascript method:

```
window.scrollTo(500, 0);
```

How do I set my arguments to make it scroll to only half the page?

Comment: You'll have to calculate the size of the window, divide it by to, and scroll to that

Comment: I think `window.innerHeight` will do the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the document's height instead of window height, you need `document.body.scrollHeight`.

```js
function scrollHalf(){
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2);
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 3000px;
  background: #0fc0fc;
}
body:before{
  top: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  background: orangered;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button onClick = 'scrollHalf()'>
  Scroll
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.scrollTo(0, window.innerHeight / 2);
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

If you need the height of the entire page, select the `<body>` tag and get the height of it. Note that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].offsetHeight
```